# How can I group identical middleware in zend-expressive?

Tags: php, mezzio

I have 2 groups of routes (web and api):

[image]

Here is an web routes example:

```
return function (Application $app, MiddlewareFactory $factory, ContainerInterface $container): void {

    $app->get('/', [
        Zend\Expressive\Session\SessionMiddleware::class,
        Zend\Expressive\Flash\FlashMessageMiddleware::class,
        User\Service\Auth\TemplateAuthMiddleware::class,
        Dev\Handler\IndexPageHandler::class
    ], 'home');

    $app->route('/auth/login', [
        Zend\Expressive\Session\SessionMiddleware::class,
        Zend\Expressive\Flash\FlashMessageMiddleware::class,
        User\Service\Auth\OnlyForGuestsMiddleware::class,
        User\Service\Auth\TemplateAuthMiddleware::class,
        User\Handler\LoginPageHandler::class
    ], ['GET', 'POST'], 'auth.login');


    $app->route('/auth/register', [
        Zend\Expressive\Session\SessionMiddleware::class,
        Zend\Expressive\Flash\FlashMessageMiddleware::class,
        User\Service\Auth\OnlyForGuestsMiddleware::class,
        User\Service\Auth\TemplateAuthMiddleware::class,
        User\Handler\ResetPageHandler::class
    ], ['GET', 'POST'], 'auth.register');

    ...
};
```

I noticed that many middleware are repeated. I want to group some middleware.
For example:

```
'web' => [
    Zend\Expressive\Session\SessionMiddleware::class,
    Zend\Expressive\Flash\FlashMessageMiddleware::class,
    User\Service\Auth\TemplateAuthMiddleware::class,
]
```

I know that zend-expressive does not support widdleware groups like laravel5. Are there a beautiful grouping solution for this?

Comment: Have you read this reference on nested middleware? https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-03-15-nested-middleware-in-expressive.html

Comment: yes, but this article is old.

Application is initialized differently:
https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive/blob/master/src/Application.php#L44

Also, I'm not sure I want a new Application instance each time.